# Custom ActionBar Listview selected color

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using a custom action bar so i have create an xml file namedthemes into @drawable/menu/themes.xml with my code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
     parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
     parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<item name="android:background">#2d73c4</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Also i create a .xml file name actionbar placed into @drawable/menu/actionbar.xml with my code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Αναζήτηση"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>

</menu>
```

So i want when i use a listview, on my selected item to be changed color.
I tried this line in my themes.xml but it didnt work.

```
 <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Can't quiet understand your question, you have a listview, when you select one item, your actionbar should change its color? Which color? background?

Comment: Exactly.Till now when i select item doesnt change background color.

Comment: have you added a `Toolbar` widget in your app? You can find it by id and set its background color in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using a `Toolbar` or `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` widget for your action bar, then I take a example for using `Toolbar` widget here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Then in you page which includes the `ListView` for changing the background color of action bar, you can include this `Toolbar`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in code behind find this `Toolbar` by its id and subscribe the `ItemSelected` event of listview:

```
public Toolbar toolbar;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetActionBar(toolbar);

    ListView lv = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.lv);

    lv.ItemSelected += Lv_ItemSelected;
}
```

Finally set the background color for example like this:

```
private void Lv_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{

   toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Color.BlueViolet);
}
```

Of course you can find the item's info in the `AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs`, and according to the args to set the color.

Comment: I'm not using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. Unfortunately it doesnt work.But also i tried this in MyListViewAdapter and it works.  row.click+=delegate{.SetBackgroundColor(Color.BlueViolet);}; But then it doesnt work my main activity code in item click event

Comment: @Dim, both `Toolbar` and `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` can work, and my sample uses `Toolbar`. I don't know why your code doesn't work, it works fine by my side, and the event I used is `ItemSelected `,  maybe you can share your sample, or more code of your main activity, both xml code and backend code.